# BigQuery: Split monthly data into days

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I want to create a new table from the existing data:

| date | store | cost |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-10 | a | 3000 |
| 2022-01-10 | b | 2500 |

And finally the targettable should look like:

| date | store | cost |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-10 | a | 96,77 |
| 2022-02-10 | a | 96,77 |
| 2022-03-10 | a | 96,77 |
| 2022-04-10 | a | 96,77 |
| .... to last day of the month | a | 96,77 |
| 2022-01-10 | b | 80,65 |
| 2022-02-10 | b | 80,65 |
| 2022-03-10 | b | 80,65 |
| ... | b | 80,65 |

The query should insert into another bigquery table with new rows for each day of the month (like the 2nd table). The cost should devided by the day of the month to split the cost.

I tried a few querys, but cant find a solution! :(

Thank you!

Comment: You want the monthly cost divided by the number of days in the month, and then a row for each day with that evenly divided cost?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bigquery SQL: Create new table. Split monthly value to daily](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70663402/bigquery-sql-create-new-table-split-monthly-value-to-daily)

Answer (score 0):

Using this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62559027/2132593) I have calculated the number of days for each month, and then I have divided the monthly costs by it to get `daily_avg_monthly_cost` . Then I Joined with an array generated table containing all the dates in each month of the year and got the final output.

Please note: a limitation of this solution is that the value "2022" is hardcoded.

```
WITH source_data as (
    SELECT date('2022-01-10') as _month, 'a' as store, 3000 as cost
    UNION ALL
    SELECT date('2022-01-10') as _month, 'b' as store, 2500 as cost
    UNION ALL
    SELECT date('2022-02-10') as _month, 'a' as store, 4000 as cost
    UNION ALL
    SELECT date('2022-02-10') as _month, 'b' as store, 3500 as cost
 ), cost_table AS (
        SELECT
            FORMAT_DATE('%Y-%m', _month) AS month,
            store,
            cost/EXTRACT(DAY FROM (DATE_SUB(DATE_TRUNC(DATE_ADD(_month, INTERVAL 1 MONTH), MONTH),INTERVAL 1 DAY))) daily_avg_monthly_cost
        FROM source_data
),days AS (
        SELECT
            d, 
            FORMAT_DATE('%Y-%m',d) AS month
            FROM (
                SELECT 
                    *
                FROM
                UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY('2022-01-01', '2022-12-31', INTERVAL 1 DAY)) AS d 
            )
)
    SELECT
        days.d as date,
        cost_table.store,
        cost_table.daily_avg_monthly_cost
    FROM cost_table
    JOIN days ON CAST(cost_table.month AS STRING) = days.month
```